# Sending E-mail when ms access.exe hangs powershell

Tags: powershell

I would like to ask for help if there is a way to send an e-mail notification when a scheduled ms access macro in task scheduler is in "Running" state for more than 20 minutes?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  I don't think anyone is going to write the code for you, but if you have some you wrote that has issues, I'm sure you'll get some help.

Comment: Hello boxdog,  so far i have tried to use "Stop the existing instance" in task scheduler as my first step just to check if i can terminate the process if it's running for more than 20mins., and for my 2nd step i planning to try midacts 1st suggestion,

Answer (score 1):

First thing that comes to mind is writing a second scheduled tasks to poll the runtime of the MS Access macro task.

If the task is over 20 minutes send out an email.

Another option might be to start a background job (`Start-Job`) in the MS Access code that will send the email after 20 minutes. And in your code, if the MS Access job succeeds you can cancel (`Stop-Job`) the email background task.

(There are many ways to skin a cat so just finding the best solution for the problem really)

Answer (score 0):

Finally got it using powershell.

```
$ScheduledTaskName = "full path of your scheduled task e.g Folder1\Folder2\taskname"
$Result = (schtasks /query /FO LIST /V /TN $ScheduledTaskName  | findstr "Result")
$Result = $Result.substring(12)
$Code = $Result.trim()

If ($Code -gt 0) {

$From = "MacroFails@DoNotReply.com"
$To = "Admin@Domain.com"
$Subject = "Scheduled task 'AppendCreatedSO' failed on SERVER"
$Body = "Error code: $Code"
$SMTPServer = "your SMTP Server"
$SMTPPort = "SMTP erver port"
Send-MailMessage -From $From -to $To -Subject $Subject -Body $Body -BodyAsHtml -SmtpServer $SMTPServer -Port $SMTPPort #-UseSsl -Credential (Get-Credential) #-Attachments $Attachment
}
```